# pass multiple rows into a function

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I have a function

```
def get_similar_row(rows, target):
    """Return the index of the most similar row"""
    return np.argmax(cosine_similarity(rows, [target]))


get_similar_row([[1191, 3, 0, 1, 1], 
                 [3251, 2, 1, 0, 0], 
                 [1641, 1, 1, 1, 0]], [2133, 3, 0, 0, 1])
```

Instead of manually inputting numbers while calling the function, I want to pass all rows of my data frame `df` such that I skip the id and pass in all other variables for all rows. This is for the `rows` parameter of the function.

```
id  size    numberOfPlants  balcony   available  publicTransport    
0   1191    3               0         1           1
1   3251    2               1         0           0
2   1641    1               1         1           0
3   2133    3               0         0           1
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`DataFrame.drop`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.drop.html) for remove `id` column, convert to numpy array and pass to function:

```
#target id
id1 = 3

#convert id to index if necessary
df1 = df.set_index('id')

#selected row by id
target = df1.loc[id1]

#removed target row from original data
get_similar_row(df1.drop(id1).to_numpy(), target.to_numpy())
```

Comment: For example, if I want to check which row is the most similar to my third row. Here, the third row is target. The id is 2. So in my function,  ```get_similar_row(rows, target)``` I want to pass the the third row just be specifying the id ```2```. But I want to ensure that while calculating the similarity within the function, the ```id```field is not included.

Comment: Then I need to compare my target with all other rows of the dataframe. So I need to pass all other rows in the ```rows``` parameter. But I want to exclude the third row since that's the original row that I am using as target. I also want to include the ```id```field from similarity calculation

Comment: @x89 - for me mor clear, can you check edit?